# Inheritance in CSS as in OOP?

Tags: css, inheritance

does anybody know a way or a tool how inheritance can be used in CSS independent of the structure of the elements?
Example:

```
.bg_red {
  background: red; 
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg_red_and_bold {
  //this class should inherit all the properties of the above two classes
}
```

I hope it is clear what I mean...

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way you can do that in CSS, but since you are looking for tools as well, you might look into CSS preprocessing:

- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)
- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Their `mixin` and `@extend` features should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

ability to add multiple classes to element is there for exactly that reason.

```
<div class="bg_red bold">The red and bold text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in CSS. Only thing you can do is:

```
.bg_red, .bg_red_and_bold  {
  background: red; 
}

.bold, .bg_red_and_bold  {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS does not support this.

Consider using [LESS](http://lesscss.org), which compiles to CSS and supports mixins:

```
.bg_red_and_bold {
   .bg_red();
   .bold();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want but there is aggregation:

```
<div class="bg_red bold"...
```

The div will "inherit" characteristics of both styles.